# Uploading msg files with RPC call

Tags: 2007, file-upload

I'm trying to upload some documents with metadata through the SharePoint RPC calls. Works great, untill I try to upload a file with an MSG extension; it refuses that for some reason. Are there blocked filetypes when using RPC calls and if so: if there a way to prevent them from being blocked?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, it was my own fault. The code which uploaded the documents checked for a return message in the service response. That was checking on IndexOf("msg") and thus caused an error when I uploaded my msg message (no error for other document types obviously). Changing to IndexOf("msg=") easily fixed the problem.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Has an administrator added the MSG extension to the target SharePoint Application's blocked-file list?

Comment: Uploading via explorer view or PUT request does work, so no: I don't think so. But i'll check to be sure. - edit - nope, no block.